# Phraseapp updating main language file

Tags: javascript, internationalization, translation

I have a following locale file:

```
{
  key1: "Text to translate",
  key2: "Another text to translate",
  key3: "Something else",
}
```

I want to put it to PhraseApp as a main locale, and have it translated to different locales (languages). When something changes in this file, I want to put it all over again to the PhraseApp, for example:

```
{
  key1: "Text to translate",
  key2: "Another text to translate",
  key3: "Something else",
  key4: "New text",
}
```

How could I do that? Should I take keys from this file and add them as keys to PhraseApp, and then it will get translated to different languages? If I want to update it, should I delete all keys and put the new ones? I don't see an option to create multiple keys in the PhraseApp API.

Comment: Hi, I'm from the PhraseApp team. When you have an updated locale file you can simply upload it and all new keys will be added to your project. To easier sync updated locale files you can also have a look at our [CLI client](https://phraseapp.com/docs/developers/cli). 

In case you want to also want to update the translation you can set the option "update_translations: true" via the API on the [upload endpoint](https://phraseapp.com/docs/api/v2/uploads/#create).

All updated translations will then be ready to translate by a translator.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Phraseapp... but I tried to search a while in their API documentation and could only find the documentation to [create a single key](https://phraseapp.com/docs/api/v2/keys/#create)

What you're looking for sounds to be exactly what [this other service](http://locize.com) seems to offer...

They have a [cli](https://github.com/locize/locize-cli#addingupdating-new-keys) and an [api](http://locize.com/api.html) that let's you update i.e. your `key4` in your example by calling i.e.

```
body=$(cat  << EOF
{
    "key4": "New text"
}
EOF
)
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer mysecret-very-4f2e-b123-d432d86430c6" -d $body https://api.locize.io/update/3d0aa5aa-4660-4154-b6d9-907dbef10bb2/latest/en/main
```

Or simply do it in their GUI: https://youtu.be/pae8mZzLEE0

It's even possible to instrument your website/SPA to use the [in-context editor](https://github.com/locize/locize-editor)